# Connect OpenStack and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, openstack

I have 2 clouds : OpenStack and AWS . I have 1 instance as a OpenVPN Client on my OpenStack and OpenVPN Server on AWS. I can connect using OpenVPN client. But how to add route rule to the OpenStack to connect from other instances that don't have OpenVPN client?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you install the VPNaaS service on you Openstack Installation and create a point to point network connection to AWS.